# Other managed languages beside C# for cross-platform development (on topic?)

Tags: discussion

Is this on topic?

Since virtual machines and hardware have become so smarter and faster lately, that some managed languages have been able to run code almost as fast as equivalent C++ code, I decided to pick one managed language for cross-platform development and stick with it. In the case of C#, it seems to be widely used in game development and in general, thanks to Unity and Xamarin. Are there other manages languages beside C# that could be used for cross-platform development? What tools are available for those other languages?

Comment: You seem to be a bit lost. Is this related to the CS stack exchange or to teaching computer science?

Comment: @ItamarG3 I think it has to do with self-directed learning, is that on topic here?

Comment: If worded correctly, and if made very clear that it's about self-learning, then it would be on-topic here. just be sure to use the [tag:self-learning] tag

Comment: @ItamarG3 thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll actually give an answer to the question here, but would think that the question itself belongs elsewhere. "Managed Language" is a Microsoft (only) dot-net concept. There are other languages that can be used with dot-net and so, theoretically, are managed. Java is an example since there are Java processors for dot-net.

However, cross platform development depends on a lot more than the language. More important are the libraries that you want to use since no important program is built without them. You may be able to run Java on a Mac and on Windows, but if you want to use non-standard libraries your program may not be portable, even though the language is.

So, Beware.

You can easily find a list of all dot-net languages. You can see whether those are implemented in a standard way on other (non Microsoft) platforms. Then you can look for the libraries.

The term Managed Languages doesn't mean a lot to people outside the MS ecosystem, by the way.

Comment: You're right, managed code and managed languages seem to apply only the .Net family of languages. What wold be the right term or distinction to separate languages with garbage collection, reflection/introspection, and JIT compilation, from those languages like C++? I guess that's what I was trying to use the term "managed languages" for.

Comment: This isn't a good use of the CSEducators meta. You should explore this on ComputerScience or on StackOverflow (arguable). Just be specific there about your needs, rather than using a term that may not be accurate or well-known.

Comment: Is JIT a property of the language or of the implementation. For example Java run on a Java CPU does not need any JIT. Or C++ compiled for 68000 and then run on an ARM, will need translating, probably with a JIT. This leaves garbage collection, and introspection. C was designed to run on Unix, with very small programs, that are joined together using the shell. Each process is an object, these objects are garbage collected by the OS. This leaves introspection. Which is not as useful as you may think. It is mainly used to implement short-coming in the language.

Answer (score 1):

You're question would not be on topic here, because it isn't about *teaching* computer science. It might be a better fit on [Computer Science](https://cs.stackexchange.com), but make sure to read [their tour](https://cs.stackexchange.com/tour) and/or [their help center](https://cs.stackexchange.com/help) before asking there.

Comment: The question is related to self-directed learning, is that on topic?

Comment: @rraallvv [tag:self-learning] is on topic, but look at some of those questions before posting. They're typically about things like, "would TopicX be within a curriculum for TopicY?" or "Are their suitable resources for self-directed learning in the field of TopicZ?".  Questions about the CS or SE itself are not topical here.

Comment: @BenI. I see, thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @rraallvv Thank you for taking the trouble to actually check in with the community before posting! I wish that more of the digital citizenry was so conscientious :)